# Android ListView selector not working well

Tags: android, listview, selector

`I am utilizing list selector, but its not working acoordingly. I am gettings effects after clicking list item, but there is no effect before item is clicked. Here is my code for selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/headerplain" />

    <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/headerplain" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/headerplain" />
</selector>

and I have applied it to listView as 
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        >
    </ListView>
```

Please help me to get out of this problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have `rowback` and `rowback_selected` in my drawable folder...

and Use `android:state_focused`,`android:state_selected`,`android:state_pressed`...

```
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rowback" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rowback_selected" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rowback_selected" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rowback" />
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=454) is a good tutorial explaining very well how selector works